# Asp.net form login Impossible when client date time differ from server

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

```
FormsAuthenticationUserData userData = new FormsAuthenticationUserData(member.Id, member.Role, member.Gender);
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, member.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(24), true, userData.Serialize());
string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
HttpCookie faCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
faCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(25);
Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);

string redirectUrl = FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(member.UserName, false);
Response.Redirect(redirectUrl, true);

protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    if (authCookie != null)
    {            
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
        try
        {
            WebIdentity identity = new WebIdentity(authTicket.Name, authTicket.UserData);
            WebPrincipal currentMember = new WebPrincipal(identity);
            Context.User = currentMember;
        }
        catch
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

the user cannot login when client date time is greater than server date time (make cookie null and cannot login)

what is solution?

thanx a lot!

Comment: You are setting the cookie to last 25 hours. Are you saying it doesn't work if the client is set 25 hours ahead of server time or ahead even by a minute?

Comment: for example when date time of client is incorrect and 10 day is greater than server. the condition of login is the client date time must be like or near the server date

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comment, this is expected behaviour that cannot be changed. The system is doing what it is meant to. You could set the cookie expire later or use a rolling timeout, however, I see no reason for the machine datetime to be out by so far.

Comment: in my idea the web app must be independent of client system date time.

Comment: Not with a cookie. The browser is receiving an expired cookie and ignoring it like it should.

Comment: we can send client date time to server. and add 25 hr to cookie

Comment: Is that a question or a statement? You could but you have to bear in mind that sending the client datetime will require client side processing to send it BEFORE the server side processing of send cookie. That means another page load.

Comment: @mmtemporary - any idea how to implement it when cookie is not created manually, like when using the authentication cookie which is created automatically when using the authentication login?

Answer (score 0):

This technique avoids using the browser's date/time completely.

1. Set the FormsAuthentication cookie to never expire, or to expire after 100 years.
2. Store the actual expiration based on server time in the authenticationTicket.Expiration property.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.aspx).
3. After the server authenticates a request, it should check the authenticationTicket.Expiration to see if it has expired.  I'm not 100% sure the system does this automatically, you may have to hook into the Application_AuthenticateRequest event and do it yourself.
4. If it has expired, the web server should deny the request; render an HTTP 403 status code and a set-cookie header to remove the cookie at that point.